# Editing Notification List/whatsapp

Tags: notification, browser, whatsapp

I'm using 20.04 Ubuntu.
I want to add/enable WhatsApp notifications on the Notification list and pop-up as other programs.
It normally just shows up in my browser.

Is there a way to integrate that feature?

Answer (score 0):

It seems editing the browser options was enough for me.
I enabled the Notifications for URL of WhatsApp (which was in default setting and i wasn't able to get notifications). Than new messages stared to appear as other notifications.

BR,